# How do I limit the amount of slider movements in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write an App where the sum of all the slider values cannot be greater than some number. See the code below for an example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

sliderInput("slider1",
                     "Slider 1",
                     min = 0,
                     max = 5,
                     value = 0),

sliderInput("slider2",
                     "Slider 2",
                     min = 0,
                     max = 5,
                     value = 0),

verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$text <- renderPrint({2*input$slider1 + 5*input$slider2})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I want there to be a restriction such that `input$slider1 + input$slider2 <= 5`. I essentially want the App to prevent users from setting `input$slider1` to 3 or more if `input$slider2` is set to 3. I'm not sure where in the code I would put something like that or how to go about it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `renderUI` and `uiOutput`. Here's an example that causes the maximum of the second slider to be driven by the value of the first.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('slider1'),
    uiOutput('slider2'),
    verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$text <- renderPrint({
        text = paste0("max:", maxslider(), " s1:", s1(), " s2:", s2())
        text
    })
    s1 <- reactive({
        ifelse(is.null(input$slider1), 0, input$slider1)
    })
    s2 <- reactive({
        ifelse(is.null(input$slider2), 0, input$slider2)
    }) 
    maxslider = reactive({
        5 - s1()  #subtract s2() to make the max depend on both sliders
    })
    output$slider1 <- renderUI({
        sliderInput('slider1', 'Slider 1', value=s1(), min=0, max=5) # change to maxslider() to make slider1 constrained
    })
    output$slider2 <- renderUI({
        sliderInput('slider2', 'Slider 2', value=s2(), min=0, max=maxslider())
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I left some comments in to allow both sliders to be changed based on their combined values. It works OK but you have to contend with the new maximum being more than a current value causing ugly reset issues. Anyway, hopefully this is a start for you.